# How to use Python decorators so that a method uses functools.lru_cache andregisters itself?

Tags: python, caching, functional-programming, python-decorators, python-class

I am decorating some methods in a class that accesses a datastore with lru_cache. I would like to apply another decorator, or to call lru_cache in another way, in order to add the caching method to a set the first time it is called. That way, when I know my datastore is dirty, I can clean the cache of each method. In other words, how do I build "register_data_reader" below ? Or should I do it another way ?

```
from functools import lru_cache
class foo:

    _cached_funcs = set()

    @register_data_reader  # adds the LRU DECORATED func to _cached_funcs
    @lru_cache(maxsize=16)
    def reads_data_somewhere(self, ...)
        ...
        return data

    def clear_cache(self):
        for f in _cached_funcs:
            f.cache_clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought on how to implement this...  Why even bother registering the methods with a decorator and tracking them in `_cache_funcs`?  Instead iterate over the classes methods and try to run `.cache_clear()` on them?

```
class Foo:

    @lru_cache(maxsize=16)
    def reads_data_somewhere(self):
        return 2 + 2

    def clear_cache(self):
        for method in dir(self):
            try:
                getattr(self, method).cache_clear()
            except AttributeError:
                pass


f = Foo()

print(f.reads_data_somewhere())
print(f.reads_data_somewhere())
print(f.reads_data_somewhere())
print(f.reads_data_somewhere())

print(f.reads_data_somewhere.cache_info())
f.clear_cache()
print(f.reads_data_somewhere.cache_info())
```

Output:

```
4
4
4
4
CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=1, maxsize=16, currsize=1)
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=16, currsize=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Terry, that was useful.

In the end, I am running the following method in the **init** of my class, inspired by yours. It allowed me to bypass throwing an exception, and I'm registering once cached methods, as there are relatively few compared to the total number.

```
Class foo:

    ...

    def _register_cache(self):
        lst = dir(self)
        for method in lst:
            if hasattr(getattr(self, method), "cache_info"):
                self._cached_methods.add(method)
```